# how to use non-static function inside of static function

Tags: java

Here is the my class..

```
public class Oop {
    int count = 0;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        this.count(15, 30);
        System.out.print(this.count);
    }

    public void count(int start, int end)
    {
       for(;start<end; start++)
       {
           this.count = this.count + start;
       }
    }
}
```

I can't call count function inside of main function. Reason is static and non-static functions. I'm really new for Java. How can i use count inside of main? What i need to learn?

Comment: Now, *search* for the error message [removing the non-generic names] on SO as there are many duplicates. You *must* create an instance to invoke a non-static method upon it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to instantiate Oop and then call the method with it, like this:

```
Oop oop = new Oop();
oop.count(1,1);
```

For further information check this out: [Difference between Static methods and Instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods)

Answer (score 2):

You should make the `count` function and the `count` variable `static` too.

Answer (score 1):

That's the least of your worries - once you've called the method, you won't be able to access the result.

You must create an instance of your class, and use that instance to *call* your method *and* get the result:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Oop oop = new Oop();
    oop.count(15, 30);
    System.out.print(oop.count);
}
```