# How to call a method with out object reference?

Tags: java

How to call a method with out object reference.

I tried this calling this by

```
Byte().add();
```

I am getting an error

Comment: Please Please show us the full code.

Comment: Learn Java from basics & study the difference between static and non static methods.

Comment: Search for the error message. Whatever error message it is, there are *many* duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call an instance method without an object reference. The instance method belongs, by definition, to an instance of the object's class.

If the method were `static`, then you could call it using the name of the class. Static methods belong to the class definition itself, so no instance is required.

Also, your syntax is off, it's not

```
Byte().add();
```

It's

```
Byte.add(); //static method
```

or

```
new Byte().add() //instance method or static method, either can be called this way.
```

Comment: @user3260955 No problem. You can mark this question closed and answer as accepted by clicking the check mark under my score above, unless you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You cant call an instance method without an `Object reference`. But if the method is `static` you can call it with class.

If you want to call a method without making an instance make that method `static`. Please learn [difference between static and instance method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods)