# What is the difference between a call to a class method and a call to an instance method?

Tags: java

I want to know the difference between a **call to a class method** and a **call to an instance method**?

Isn't a class method something like:

```
identifier();
```

and a instance method like:

```
object.identifier();
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can call both static and instance methods in both ways, depending on the situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Static methods and Instance methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods)

Answer (score 1):

(I think, you mean `.();` to be something like `myClassInstance.myMethod();` If true, then: )

Class methods are `static` methods which can be called as the class loaded. They don't need an instance of the class to be called. Assume that you created a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public static void classMethod() {
        /* Something to do (statically) here */
    }
    public void instanceMethod() {
        /* Some thing to do here */
    }
```

As you can see, once you import your class in your working area, you could call the static (class) method, like this:

```
MyClass.classMethod();
```

But not the instance method, calling the instance method needs an instance of the class to be called, like this:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.instanceMethod();
```

Also notice that you could only `static` works (!) in an `static` method. Like changing static variables or calling static functions.
This answer could help too.
[Difference between Static methods and Instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11993118/3001920)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, a **`class method`** ("static method")is a property for the WHOLE class , so its's called as `className.methodName()`.

BUT for **`instance methods`**, then each object have their own copy of them, so they r called as `objectName.instanceMethodName().`

**Second difference :**

- class ("static")methods can access ONLY static fields
- but instance methods can access ANY fields of the class .

A third a bit advanced difference is that class **`(Static) methods are bound to the class at compile time`** , while **`instance methods are bound to their objects at run time`** ..