# Creating objects in java

Tags: java, oop, object

In a socket programming code there was a line like this

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
```

What's done here? If I create an object of `InetAddress` isn't that would be like this?

```
InetAddress address = new InetAddress();
```

Comment: no, because the static method `InetAddress.getLocalHost();` returns value of type `InetAddress`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Static methods and Instance methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP needs to have a minimal understanding of programming.

Comment: @nalply By the way, where in the rules is it said that a topicstarter has to have minimal understanding of programming? It seems to me the purpose of this particular question is to get that very minimal understanding, as the person is clearly very new to programming. Should we discourage such kind of questions?

Comment: @Suseika That's a topic for Meta.

Answer (score 5):

[`InetAddress.getLocalHost()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost--) is a [`public static` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) of `InetAddress`.

> Returns the address of the local host. This is achieved by retrieving the name of the host from the system, then resolving that name into an InetAddress.

There are many cases where an instance is not created by you using a constructor but by a static method like this or by a factory.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html), there isn't an implemented constructor for `InetAddress`.

Instead, you need to use some `static` methods that return an `InetAddress`, such as `getLocalHost()`.