# Non-static method referenced from a static context

Tags: java, static, non-static

I have two errors both the same and they follow below:

```
class FBox {//...}
class FBPlayer
{
    //Initialized instances
    FBox game = new FBox();
    **FBPillar pillar = new FBPillar();**
    **FBObjects objects = new FBObjects();**
    //Lots o Properties...

    public boolean get_Alive() { return this.b_PlayerAlive; }
    public void set_Alive(boolean alive) { this.b_PlayerAlive = alive; }

    //My Error ridden Method
    public void checkCollision()
    {
        if(get_YPos() >= **objects**.get_Ground())
                          ^My Error was incorrect name for my instance
        {
            set_Alive(false);
        }
        else if(get_Bounds().intersects(**pillar**.get_Bounds()))   
                                ^My Error was incorrect name for my instance
        {
            set_Alive(false);
        } 
    }

class FBPillar
{
    public int get_Bounds() {return 'the variable'; }
}

class FBObjects
{
    public int get_Ground() {return 'the variable'; }
}
```

The error is in the if statement as well as the else if statement
When i run it it returns the error:

```
FBox.java:178: error: non-static method get_Bounds() cannot be referenced from a static context
               else if(get_Bounds().intersects(**FBPillar**.get_Bounds()))
```

The same error for the if statement but with FBObjects.get_Ground())
                                                           ^

Comment: Do you know what static and non-static methods are?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods/11993118#11993118

You are referencing a non-static method as though it were a static method. You *must* instantiate an object to access a non-static method on it.

Comment: Turn your head slightly to the right and scroll down to the _Related_ section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whose bounds are you talking about?  You probably mean

```
if (get_Bounds().intersects(pillar.get_Bounds())) {
    …
}
```

I'd also add that

```
 FBPlayer player = new FBPlayer();
```

means that a player contains a player, which is probably isn't what you intended.

Comment: Thanks 200_success now i feel very stupid...