# Refresh button in action bar of android app

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i m very new into android app. I m trying to execute an app that should contain a refresh button in the action bar. While compiling a code, the studio is prompting this error

"Error:(50, 20) error: non-static method reload() cannot be referenced from a static context"

I have written this uptil now

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView = new WebView(this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    final Activity activity = this;
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    setContentView(mWebView);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_refresh){
        WebView.reload();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/refresh_button"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `WebView.reload()` to `mWebView.reload()`

In the former case, you are calling `reload()` on the `WebView` *class*, whereas in the latter you are telling your specific instance of `WebView` to reload.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods) may clarify things a bit more.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explaination. It worked. However the refresh button is in the menu list, how can I make it visible as an icon? 
I have put <item> into the main_menu.xml file

Comment: In the line `app:showAsAction="never"`, change "never" to "always" or "ifRoom". Setting it to always will force the button to be shown, whereas ifRoom will show the button if there's enough room on the screen.