# How to call a method of an object that was instantiated in another class?

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, getter

Given the three example classes:

```
public class MainClass {
    public MainClass() {
        ArrayOfObjectA arrA = new ArrayOfObjectA();
    }
}
```

,

```
public class ArrayofObjectA {
    ...
    public void doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}
```

, and

```
public class ObjectA {
    ...
    public void doThis() {
        arrA.doSomething(); // <-- Here's the issue
    }
}
```

How would I call `doSomething()` from `arrA`?

Additionally, `arrA` holds an array of `ObjectA` objects, making this problem even more complicated.

I made `arrA` a class object in `MainClass` and then had a `getArrA()` method in there, but I feel like there is a better solution to this.

Comment: What would that even mean, for the object to call something on...the array containing it?  An array it contains?

Comment: The purpose of this is to allow `ObjectA` to manipulate the other `ObjectA` objects in `arrA`. Since `arrA` contains the array of the objects, it can directly call the methods of each `ObjectA` object in the array. Therefore, if an `ObjectA` object could call that method, it would be able to indirectly call the methods of the `ObjectA` objects. Plus, the method will perform in a specific way depending on which `ObjectA` object calls `doSomething()`.

Comment: Sounds like `doThis` should accept the `ArrayofObjectA` as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectA` needs a **reference** to `arrA`. Typically this is done by passing it as a parameter to that function:

```
public class ObjectA {
    ...
    public void doThis(ArrayofObjectA arrA) {
        arrA.doSomething(); // <-- Here's the issue
    }
}
```

By doing this, you ensure that a reference is 'in scope' for that function. Normally functions can only 'see' parameters passed to them and member fields of their class. So, the other way it can call `doSomething()` is if there is a reference in the class itself:

```
public class ObjectA {
    private ArrayofObjectA arrA;

    public ObjectA(ArrayofObjectA a) {
      this.arrA = a; ///'this' is optional but makes it clear we are talking about a member field.
    }

    public void doThis(ArrayofObjectA arrA) {
        this.arrA.doSomething(); // <-- Here's the issue
    }
}
```

Note that a 'reference' is essentially some handle that allows you to refer to a particular instantiation of an object. You *need* a reference to call any non-static method. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods/11993118#11993118) for more information on the difference between those two things.

Also note that despite naming your class `ArrayofObjectA`, it is not actually an array. There is only one instance of it declared (in your `MainClass`) and it (currently) possess no references to any `ObjectA` instantiations. More properly you might name this `ArrayHolder`:

```
public class ArrayHolder {
    private ObjectA[] arrA;//note that the [] indicates it's an array.

    public ArrayHolder() {
        this.arrA = new Object[10];//Length of ten
        for (int idx=0; idx<10; idx++) {
            this.arrA[idx] = new ObjectA(this);//pass new ObjectA a REFERENCE to 'this' object (ArrayHolder)
        }
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        //This is now callable from all ObjectA objects.
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the second way just cause each ObjectA object to store an array of ObjectA objects including itself? That would be more memory heavy than going the getter-setter route.

Comment: No: it's not storing an array, it's storing a reference to an array. A reference you need in order to have access to that array.

Comment: Oh that's right, I see. Then it seems as though the second way would be the easiest to implement. Thanks.