# Fire multiple tweens simultaneously with GSAP and TweenMax

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I want to move away from jQuery for animation so I have been using GSAP. I am trying to figure out how to fire multiple animations on an element and its children. Basically I want to give the `#navicon` a "720 cork" effect which is working fine and a fade/toggle the icon to the children of this `#navicon` container which is not working at all.

If I was using jQuery only, I would have probably just add multiple classes as needed and use them to trigger some CSS3 transforms. However, GSAP seems to be [really fast](https://greensock.com/css-performance).

I have read the GSAP docs pretty thoroughly. And I see how to chain tweens with "timeline" but I am not sure how to fire multiple tweens on different elements based on one event.

Here is my code so far:

```
var toggleMobiMenu = function() {
    $('#navicon').on('click touchstart', function() {
        TweenMax.to($(this), 0.5, { rotationY: 720, rotationX: -720 })
            .to($(this).find('#open'), 0.5, { opacity: 0 })
            .to($(this).find('#closed'), 0.5, { opacity: 1 });
    });
}
toggleMobiMenu();
```

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w609va8d/) is the fiddle of the same. Does anyone know how to tween all these 3 elements at once?

Comment: hey @HelloWorld, did my suggestion below help?

Comment: @TahirAhmed I ended up solving the problem another way, but thanks for catching my stupid mislabeling of '#navicon-open' and 'navicon-closed'!

Comment: I think you missed to read the **Snippet** part of my answer where I have mentioned **`TimelineMax`** ;)

Comment: Because in your solution, I believe you are still not making the most of it. You are creating a new instance of **`TimelineLite`** upon every click. Instead you should have one pre-defined instance that you only play *forward* or *backward*.

Comment: Plus, you seem to be only *adding* to the animation queue of a timeline using the **`to`** method where as, as stated above, there should actually be only one timeline instance already defined outside the scope of the click handler and only utilized within.

Comment: And lastly, instead of using a flag to know animation direction, you can utilize **`TimelineMax`** very own **`reversed()`** property.

Comment: Take a look at my **Snippet** below again which addresses the issues I just raised. And let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @HelloWorld there is really no need to use `this` and `find()` if you are targeting a selector ID. You should only have one element with that specific ID on your web page anyway. An `ID` is a unique identifier so if you have multiple ID's with the same ID you need to make them unique. Plus targeting just the ID is faster without `this` and `find()` .. so just use `.to('#open', 0.5, { opacity: 0 })` and `.to('#closed', 0.5, { opacity: 1 });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems in your code:

- The method **`to`** of **`TweenMax`** is a static method but what it
  returns is an *instance* of **`TweenMax`**. Read more about the
  difference between static and instance methods
  [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11993118) and this is basically a
  language agnostic concept. Since, in this case, the instance does not
  have a **`to`** method available to it [**as per the
  docs**](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/to/), your code
  breaks.
- Second problem with the code is that you are using **`find()`** method to find **`#open`** and **`#close`** elements inside **`#navicon`** element when clicked, but as per your HTML structure, there are no such things as **`#open`**
  and **`#close`** elements. Instead you have **`#navicon-open`** and **`#navicon-close`** elements. Putting them instead of the old ones should fix that.

So all in all, your code should look like this:

```
var toggleMobiMenu = function() {
    $('#navicon').on('click touchstart', function() {
        TweenMax.to($(this),0.5,{rotationY:720,rotationX:-720});
        TweenMax.to($(this).find('#navicon-open'),0.5,{opacity:0});
        TweenMax.to($(this).find('#navicon-close'),0.5,{opacity:1});
    });
}
toggleMobiMenu();
```

But if I understand it correctly, what you are really trying to do is to come up with an animation that moves forward or backward i.e. *toggles* every time the icon is clicked. So I have reworked the code in the snippet below provided you an idea of just that:

***Snippet:***

```js
var navIcon=$('#navicon');
var navIconOpen=$('#navicon-open');
var navIconClose=$('#navicon-close');
var timeline=new TimelineMax({paused:true,reversed:true});
var duration=.6;
var ease=Power2.easeOut;
var rotation=360;
var init=function(){
    timeline.to(navIcon,duration,{rotationY:rotation,rotationX:-rotation,ease:ease},0);
    timeline.to(navIconOpen,duration,{opacity:0,ease:ease},0);
    timeline.to(navIconClose,duration,{opacity:1,ease:ease},0);
    navIcon.on('click touchstart',function(){
        toggleMobileMenu();
    });
};
var toggleMobileMenu=function(){
    timeline.reversed()?timeline.play():timeline.reverse();
};
//
init();
```

```css
#navicon {
 height:45px;
 width:45px;
 border:#000 3px solid;
 border-radius:50%;
 margin:5px 35px 0 0;
 position:relative;
 float:right;
}

#navicon i {
 color:#000;
 top:8px;
 left:11px;
 font-size:24px;
 position:absolute;
}

#navicon #navicon-open {
 opacity:1;
}

#navicon #navicon-close {
 opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="navicon" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <i id="navicon-open" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    <i id="navicon-close" class="fa fa-times"></i>
</a>
```

Hope this helps.