# Understanding OOP and static in Java

Tags: java, oop

Suppose you have `class A` and `class B`. `Class A` is the main class which builds a frame with a GUI. It contains all the GUI variables (such as buttons, labels, strings) along with whatever methods that you'll be using. `Class A` also creates a `class B` object:

```
ClassB name = new ClassB();
```

Inside `class B` you will find a **for loop**. Now, once the for loop is finished looping, I want to call a method located in `class A`. Whenever I try calling a method located in `class A`, Eclipse suggests making that method `static`. I'm trying to avoid making static methods. Is there a way of calling `class A`'s methods from `class B` without making anything static?

Class A:

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

// init variables
private JPanel contentPane;
private JPanel panel_actions;
private JButton btn_strike;
private JProgressBar progBar_loading;

private Load load;

// create the frame
public dsgsd() {

    load = new Load();

    // frame initializing
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setBounds(100, 100, 890, 480);
    setTitle("BeyondInfinity - Group Project for CS1100");
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);

    // create a root panel
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    contentPane.setBounds(0, 0, 884, 451);
    contentPane.setVisible(true);
    getContentPane().add(contentPane);

    // create actions panel for displaying attack buttons
    panel_actions = new JPanel();
    panel_actions.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    panel_actions.setBounds(10, 306, 854, 68);
    panel_actions.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
    panel_actions.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 6, 10, 0));
    panel_actions.setVisible(true);
    contentPane.add(panel_actions);

    // create attack button #1
    btn_strike = new JButton("Strike");
    btn_strike.setFocusable(false);
    btn_strike.setVisible(true);
    btn_strike.addActionListener(this);
    panel_actions.add(btn_strike);

}

// create action listener
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    if (evt.getSource().equals(btn_strike)) {
        load.start();
    }
}

public void executeTasks() {
    //TODO do something 
}

// set value for the loading bar
public void setProgBar_loading(int val) {
    progBar_loading.setValue(val);
    progBar_loading.repaint();
}


}
```

Class B:

```
public class Load {
  private Timer timer;
  private int i;

  public void start() {
    // reset loading bar
    Game.setProgBar_loading(0);
    i = 0;

    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (i > 100) {
                timer.stop();
                Game..executeTasks();
            } else
                Game.setProgBar_loading(i++);

        }
    };
    // timer which triggers the actionlistener every 15ms
    timer = new Timer(15, listener);
    timer.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be beneficial here. Your GUI most likely shouldn't have static methods.

Comment: To call a method of an object, you need to have a reference to that object. So A should pass a reference to itself (`this`) to B, so that B can call A's method.

Comment: "*I'm trying to avoid making static methods.*" why? what do you think is wrong with static methods? Also Eclipse doesn't *insist* on anything. If you don't like a suggestion it's making, turn it off. Compilation errors, of course, are a different story. Are you getting a compilation error? Either way, actual code and error messages would be helpful.

Comment: @dimo414 *cannot reference non-static symbol from static context* is not a suggestion

Comment: @cricket_007 that's a compiler error, nothing to do with Eclipse. We're all just going off of the OPs vague description but I interpreted the question as referring to a method that Eclipse suggests could be static.

Comment: I added my code to the post.

Comment: @cricket_007, it calls it more than once; it's not always `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call non-static methods of an **object**, but you can only call static methods on a **class**. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods/11993118#11993118) for more information on the difference between the two. To be able to call a method on an object of type `ClassA`, you'd have to do something like this:

```
public class ClassA {
  public method myNonStaticMethod() { ... }
}

public class ClassB {
  private ClassA a;

  public ClassB(ClassA a) {
    this.a = a;  //This makes sure this *object* has a *reference* to an object of *type* ClassA.
  }

  public void looping() {
    //some looping code
    this.a.myNonStaticMethod(); //Actually call the nonstatic method
  }
}
```

Note that any class that `import`s another class will have reference to that **class** and can call static methods on that class, or instantiate a new **object** of that class **type**. If you want a particular object to call a non-static method of another object, it either needs to instantiate the object itself, *or* it needs a **reference** to that other object.

In the example above, the **constructor** of `ClassB` gets a reference to a specific **object** of **type** `ClassA`, whose reference name is `a`. This is saved to a **private member field**, which can be called by any non-static method in an object of type `ClassB`.

Comment: This is very similar to @JosephRoque's solution. I is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: Agreed! Be sure you learn the correct terminology, though; the terminology describes the differences that are causing you trouble here.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need a reference to an instance of `ClassA` inside of `ClassB` to avoid static methods.

First, `ClassB` will need a field and constructor similar to the following:

```
private ClassA parent = null;

public ClassB(ClassA parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

Then, when you instantiate `ClassB`, you'll pass a reference to the current instance like so: `ClassB name = new ClassB(this)`

Finally, when you want to use your method inside `ClassB` (let's assume that method is called `doSomething()`, you can call it with `parent.doSomething()`

Comment: I just implemented your solution and it worked flawlessly! It had never occurred to me passing a whole class as a parameter! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The "proper" OOP approach to do this would be with an interface.

```
public interface Loadable {
    void reset();
    void setProgress(int progress);
    void onLoaded();
}
```

You implement this in your Game class

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Loadable {

    private JButton load_button;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    public Game() {
        // initialize
    }

    public void executeTasks() {
        //TODO do something
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(load_button)) {
            new Loader().load(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded() {
        executeTasks();
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        progressBar.setValue(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        progressBar.setValue(progress);
    }
}
```

And pass it into the `Loader`. This way, the `Loader` doesn't care the you are giving it a `Game` object. You could have any implementation of `Loadable` that this `Loader` can load.

```
public class Loader {
    private Timer timer;
    private int i;

    public void load(final Loadable l) {
        // reset loading bar
        l.reset();
        i = 0;

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                l.setProgress(++i);

                if (i >= 100) {
                    timer.stop();
                    l.onLoaded();
                }

            }
        };
        // timer which triggers the actionlistener every 15ms
        timer = new Timer(15, listener);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To call any non-static method of A, you need a class instance of A. Do you have one inside class B? If you don't then you can't call a non-static method. A static method can be called without the instance (as long as it is accessible) like this A.method1();