# Arraylist for subclasses

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a Vehicle superclass and then I have some subclasses to that one. I am trying to have an array list that adds objects from all of the subclasses into the same list, but I'm coming up short.

I currently have the list in my program class but I have moved it around a bit.

This is the code I have in Program:

```
ArrayList<Vehicles> Inventorie = new ArrayList<>();

public void setInventorie(Car newCar) {
    Inventorie.add(newCar);
}
```

And this the code I have in Car:

```
public void addCar(){
    System.out.println("Make: ");
    Make = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("RegNr");
    regNr = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Year");
    year = scan.nextInt();
    setValue();
    Car c1 = new Car(make, regNr, Year);
     Program.setInventorie(c1);
}
```

In Car I am getting "Non-static method 'setInventorie(Project1.Vehicles)' cannot be referenced from static context."

I also had to comment out the main method or the compiler couldn't resolve the symbol Inventorie (name of array list).

Tried to explain my problem as best as I could, hope someone can help.
And yes, I am new to this so it might seem really stupid but it's the best I could do.

Thanks

Comment: You should study the [difference between static methods and instance methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods). You defined `setInventorie()` as an instance method but you're using it as a class (static) method. That's not allowed in Java

Comment: And read about java naming conventions. Only class names or constants start with UpperCase; variables go carInventory always ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it's the line `Program.setInventorie(c1);`.  You need to create an instance of the `Program` class and call `setInventorie()` on that.  `setInventorie()` is not a static method.

e.g.:

```
Program myProgram = new Program();
myProgram.setInventorie(c1);
```

Comment: I didn't post all the code but I have that in Program: Car c1 = new Car();

Comment: You didn't spend much time learning the basic stuff. Just turn to the duplicated question I linked to.

Comment: @brodude, see my answer: "You need to create an instance of the **Program** class and call setInventorie() on that."

Comment: Not quite sure how it is the same. The answers in that thread says create an instance and my post you replied to said I have an instance?

Comment: @SteveSmith Thanks, I did that now but I'm still getting the non-static error message.

Comment: Update the question with your new code.

Comment: Sorry, I did it wrong the first time. Your solution worked. Big thanks!