# why is this instance not inheriting from Object?

Tags: javascript

If every object inherits from `Object` why does `console.log(e.hasOwn(test1.prototype,"eu"))` give me this error?

> Uncaught TypeError: e.hasOwn is not a function

```js
function test1() {
  this.senha = "ooopa";
}

test1.word = "any"
test1.prototype.eu = "true"

function test2() {
  this.name = "euler";
}

var t = new test2();
var e = new test1();

console.log(Object.hasOwn(test1.prototype, "eu"));
console.log(e.hasOwn(test1.prototype, "eu"));
```

Comment: `hasOwn` is not an *instance* method. It's a static method on `Object` itself.

Comment: Every object inherits from the `Object.prototype` object; `hasOwn` is NOT defined in the `Object.prototype` object.

Answer (score 2):

[`Object.hasOwn()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) is a static method. Static methods are directly called on the class.

In this case it will be directly called on `Object`.

Other examples are `Object.keys()`,`Object.entries()`.

[Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251894/javascript-static-method-vs-instance-method#:%7E:text=if%20it%27s%20a%20static%20method,(usually%20in%20the%20constructor).)

JS has prototype inheritance. Properties are looked up using the prototype chain. If a property is attached to the `prototype` then it will be available to the instances. Example: [`Object.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Comment: Not to be confused for `Array.prototype.keys()` and `Array.prototype.entries()` ;)

Comment: Definitely. Added it to be more clear hopefully