# Can't acces a public method from a public class outside the class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm building a SQlite database for a android quiz app. In Helper class I created a public method getAllQuestions(), but for some reason I can't access this method(or any other method in the helper class) in MainActivity. BTW I imported this class to Main but it doesn't help.

this is the code:

```
public class DB_Helper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PRO_QUIZ";
    public static final  int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public  ArrayList<QuestionsDataBase> getAllQuestions() {

        ArrayList<QuestionsDataBase> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        String Projection [] ={
                QuestionTable._ID,
                QuestionTable.Column_Question,
                QuestionTable.Column_Option1,
                QuestionTable.Column_Option2,
                QuestionTable.Column_Option3,
                QuestionTable.Column_Option4,
                QuestionTable.Column_Correct_Ans
        };
        Cursor c = db.query(QuestionTable.Table_Name, Projection, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                QuestionsDataBase questions = new QuestionsDataBase();
                questions.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Question)));
                questions.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Option1)));
                questions.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Option2)));
                questions.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Option3)));
                questions.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Option4)));
                questions.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Correct_Ans)));
                questionsList.add(questions);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        return questionsList;
    }
```

However, when I type in Main: DB_Helper. I cant see any methods.

Comment: well it doesn't seem like your methods are static, are you creating a new instance correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

The method `getAllQuestions()` is not `static`. That means that you need an instance of `DB_Helper` to access that method (you get an instance of an object with the keyword `new`). So do this:

```java
DB_Helper dbHelper = new DB_Helper();
dbHelper.getAllQuestions();
```

or alternatively you can declare the method as static this way:

```java
public static ArrayList getAllQuestions(){
    ...
}
```

And then access it as you wanted in the first palce:

```java
DB_Helper.getAllQuestions();
```

But beware that in this case (doing it `static`) you will also need to declare all class variables used in that method as `static` too:

```java
private static SQLiteDatabase db;
```

Recommended further reading: [Difference between Static methods and Instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods/43171873)

Comment: Oh I see now. Actually I created an instance (DB_helper db = new DB_helper), but for some reason I was trying  calling the method through the class itself, aka DB_Helper. and not db. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! Solved then. Please accept the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: You wouldn't be able to declare `DB_Helper.getAllQuestions()` as static (aside from bad practice) as it calls `SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase()`.