# Can I use a non-static method in another non static method?

Tags: java

Whenever I try to call a non static method, I always get the error "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context".
Anyways this can be solved?

````
        
        int pages; 
        
        pages = content.length()/ 700; 
        
        if (content.length()%700!= 0) { 
            pages = pages+1;
        }
        return pages;
        
    } ```
```public double getPrice(int index){
        
        double price = 0;
        int pages = Book.getPages();
        
        if (index == 0){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            
        }
        else {
             price = (locationFactor * ()); 
             
        }
            
            
            
        
        return price;
    }```
````

Comment: Which line in the code shown produces that error?  Is it `Book.getPages()`?  Where do you define the variable `Book`?  If it's a class name and not a variable instance, that's the problem.  Semantically, one would get the number of pages from a specific "book", not from the concept of a "book".

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods