# non-static method openConnection() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, javafx

The problem appears in `openConnection()`.
I've tried all solutions and they didn't work. Can someone save me and write the solution in details that I can understand it?

```java
package cabinet.database;

import cabinet.Admin;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class logincc {
        Statement st;

  public boolean islogin(Admin ad)throws SQLException{
         st= Connection.openConnection().createStatement();
    ResultSet res=  st.executeQuery("select*from mote de passe where username ='"+ad.getUsername()+"'and password='"+ ad.getPassword()+"'" );
    if (res.next())
  return true;
  return false;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you need to know that isn’t explained by the error message? `openConnection()` is an instance method, you can’t call it with a class name (the “static context”)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error in the title, [this question might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077). Non-static methods need an instance, such as `new Connection()` and can't be called without creating an instance.

I'm not sure what library you're using to create the connection but [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm) shows an example of how you would do this in Java.