# Using static methods in controller Javalin

Tags: java, javalin

after seeing few projects on GitHub I've been thinking, should I use static methods in my controller? I use Javalin and I created NoteController class to service all requests. What's the difference between my idea and the other one, to use static methods and don't create instance of NoteController?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        NoteController controller = new NoteController();

        Javalin app = Javalin.create(javalinConfig -> javalinConfig.staticFiles.add("/public"))
                .start();
        app.routes(()-> {
           path("notes", ()->{
                post(controller::insertNote);
                get(controller::getNotes);
                delete(controller::deleteNote);
                put(controller::updateNote);
           });
```

```
public void insertNote(Context ctx){
        database.insertNote(gson.fromJson(ctx.body(), Note.class));
        ctx.status(200);
    }

    public void getNotes(Context ctx){
        ctx.json(gson.toJson(database.getNotes(ctx.queryParam("id"))));
        ctx.status(200);
    }

    public void deleteNote(Context ctx){
        database.deleteNote(ctx.queryParam("id"));
        ctx.status(200);
    }

    public void updateNote(Context ctx){
        database.updateNote(gson.fromJson(ctx.body(), Note.class));
        ctx.status(200);
    }
```

Is my way of doing that incorrect? If I use static methods, I won't be able to use gson object as well as database instance to do database operations

Comment: Not if they're instance variables, no, but you made the choice to make them instance variables. There's no generic way to answer whether or not something "should" be implemented a certain way.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods only have access to static objects/variables directly. In order to use any instance you will need to supply it as a parameter.

Because you're accessing an Instance of a database you should leave your code as is. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11993118/5899345) for a precise difference between Static methods and Instance methods.

Also, you don't need to call `gson#toJson` if you're using `ctx#json`, since the latter already does the JSON parsing for you. If you want to use gson you can define it as the default mapper (available since version 5.3.1):

```java
Javalin app = Javalin.create(javalinConfig -> {
    javalinConfig.staticFiles.add("/public");
    javalinConfig.jsonMapper(new JavalinGson());
}).start();
```