# How can I add or remove 60 from methods depending on what arrow key is pressed?

Tags: java, methods

I want to add or remove 60 from "charaposx101" or "charaposy101" depending on what arrow key is being pressed while the code (JFrame) is running. Here are some snipets of code I think are related to the question, sorry if its bearly legible, Im very new to coding

```
class MainFrame extends JComponent {
public int charaposx101=0;
public int charaposy101=0;
}
```

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame Frame = new JFrame("game");
        Frame.setSize(675, 700);
        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame.getContentPane().add(new MainFrame ());
        Frame.setVisible(true);
        Frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    System.out.println("Up Arrrow-Key is pressed!");

                }
                else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    System.out.println("Down Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
                }
                else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    System.out.println("Left Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
                }
                else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    System.out.println("Right Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
                }
            }
        }
        );
    }
}
```

I tried adding a new method to MainFrame

```
public void changeCharPos(){
(not needed)
}
```

but when I tried accessing it from Main, it would always give me an error

```
Frame.changeCharPos()
//or
MainFrame.changeCharPos()
//or
Main.changeCharPos()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods/67399528#67399528

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a method definition:

```
public void changeCharPos(){
(not needed)
}
```

And here is the invocation:

```
Frame.changeCharPos()
//or
MainFrame.changeCharPos()
//or
Main.changeCharPos()
```

The problem is that your invocation (best try is `MainFrame.changeCharPos()`) actually refences the class and tries to invoke the method. This would work, had you specified the method as `public void static changeCharPos()`.

Since you did not, you must create an instance of MainFrame and call the method on that, such as

```
new MainFrame().changeCharPos();

MainFrame m = new MainFrame();
m.changeCharPos();
```

BTW, it would have been good if you shared the error itself. It should be a compiler error.